# Setup Backbone.js to fetch from Symfony2 in dev and prod environment

Tags: symfony, backbone.js

How can I setup backbone.js or Symfony2 to talk to each other properly when in both dev and prod environments?

I have set up my route to return a JSON response at '/example', but when in Symfony2's dev environment I need backbone to send the request to /app_dev.php/example.

So in S2's **dev** environment backbone should fetch from

```
/app_dev.php/example
```

And in S2's **prod** environment, backbone should fetch from

```
/example
```

Comment: What about modifying your `.htaccess` to reroute to `app_dev.php` on your local machine only ?

Comment: @Touki That would work, but then I wouldn't be able to preview the prod environment locally before pushing changes to server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2 using assetic with Angular HTML5 routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319602/symfony2-using-assetic-with-angular-html5-routes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle).

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! This solved issue for all environments without needing to make hardcode changes all the time. Also gave me some more power with setting url in my backbone models/collections. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

What I did :

```
var base_url = "http://mylocalhost:1234/app_dev.php";

url: function() {
    return base_url + "/whatever url";
}
```

When committing, I simply changed back the base_url.

Comment: This is the (hopefully temporary) solution I came up with for now. I guess what I am hoping for is for a way for assetic to rewrite the urls in the javascript in the same way it does for css files. Or something similiar that doesn't involve the labor of manually changing the hardcoded variables every time I change environments or push changes to server.